# dynamically encode data in json with limit using php for mobile app like android , ios

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have record of 1000 and more records. I have to provide only 50 records per request like
0-50, 50-100, 100-150 like this. I'm using the following code:

```
    public function get_database($data)

    <?php
    {     
         $start          = $data['start'];
         $limit          = $data['limit']; 
         $alumni_details = array();


   $query1    = "select * from alumni where
   status='Active',limit '".$start."','".$limit."' ";

         $query_run = mysql_query($query1);

         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
         { 
              $row['date_of_birth'] = date('d M, Y',  strtotime($row['date_of_birth']));  

              $alumni_detail['alumni_details'] = $row;
              $alumni_details[]                = $alumni_detail;
         }

         echo json_encode($alumni_details);   
    }
```

But I need to take only user_id based on that I need to encode data in json dynamically with limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as below:

```
$start = $data['start'];

$query = SELECT * FROM `alumni` WHERE `status` = 'Active' ORDER BY `alumni_id` LIMIT $start,5"
```

It should be dynamic 5 would not be taken as constant. take it in some variable,
and yes it should be fixed, but as per requirement in future it can be change so take it in variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start=$data['start'];

$query=select * from alumni where status='Active' order by alumni_id Limit $start,5"
```

where 5 is the limit set it according to requirement

Answer (score 1):

$start=$data['start'];

$query=select * from alumni where status='Active' order by alumni_id Limit $start,5"

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your query string.

Use concatenation for example:

```
$query1 = "select * from alumni where status='Active' limit ".$start.",".$limit;
```

Or just put variables into double quoted string:

```
$query1 = "select * from alumni where status='Active' limit $start, $limit";
```

There is a typo also: you should use `$start` variable in the query, not `$star`